# CoreData and multithreading environment

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, synchronized

My app invloves multi-threading and I don't want anything to corrupt core-data

When it comes to variable we can safely use @Synchronized to make sure its not corrupting ...But for the core-data as a whole is there any way to do that ?

any suggestions or ways to do it are welcome

Comment: Start with the [Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH24-SW1) discussion in _Core Data Programming Guide._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use `@synchronize` with Core Data.  You just need to follow the threading rules of Core Data:

- A context can only be used on the queue that it is associated with (Main queue or Private queue)
- A managed object can only be used on the queue that the context that it is associated with belongs to (again Main queue or Private queue)

And my personal rule:

- If it is feeding the UI, use a Main Queue context (preferably a singular main queue context)
- Data processing belongs on a private queue context that is a child of the main queue context.

Follow those rules and you are guaranteed not to have threading issues.

Comment: @Macus S. Zarra What is the best way to transfer background context managed objects to main context. If I am fetching big amount of data on background context and then want to bring it in main context. What should be correct approach.

Comment: If you are fetching data for use in the UI, use the Main context, don't fetch it on a private context.  If you are talking about loading data from the network, load it on a private context and then your UI should be using a `NSFetchedResultsController` to *react* to the saving of the private child context.

Comment: S Zara thanks. While fetching 1000's of managed objects on main thread it is taking some time and UI hangs. While using your proposed core data stack I want to fetch these objects from persistent store on app launch in background context and wants to show on UI. So that's why I want to transfer these background context objects on main thread context. What should be correct way to do this.

Comment: Core Data doesn't work that way and you are not going to see a performance benefit from that.  What you want to do is build your `NSFetchRequest` so that it only pulls in the objects that you need **right now** and that it retrieves a list of the other objects so that it can work through the list with only some of them in memory at a time.  Fetching thousands of objects into memory is **BAD** for memory.  Better to use the tool the way that it is intended to be used.